# La sémantique de rapidité de « coup » participe-t-elle de la notion de « coup d'État » ?

Tags: sens, choix-de-mot, adjectifs, figure-de-style

Le TLFi classe, dans sa vedette « [coup](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/coup) », le *coup d'État* par métonymie dans une rubrique « avec une idée de promptitude, de vivacité ». On le définit comme le « [renverse](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/renverser)ment du pouvoir existant par un groupe de personnes, qui agit souvent par la force » ([Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/coup_d%E2%80%99%C3%89tat)).

La sémantique de *rapidité* du *coup* participe-t-elle de la notion ou l'emploi métonymique l'exclut-elle ; en d'autres termes un *coup d'État* peut-il être long, prendre du temps ou est-ce seulement le résultat qui constitue ce *coup*-là alors que le reste ne serait que « [tentative](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/tentative) (de) » ? Incidemment quel adjectif qualifierait les actions ou gestes menant à ce résultat (le *renversement du pouvoir*) ?

Answer (score 2):

*Coup* est bien utilisé pour indiquer un choc. Il y a donc forcément une idée de rapidité d'exécution, d'effet de surprise dans *coup d'État*. Le pouvoir légitime est mis devant le fait accompli, il n'a pas la possibilité de réagir.

Les préparatifs d'un coup d'État peuvent être longs mais c'est leur exécution que l'on nomme *coup d'État*.

Un adjectif qui peut qualifier ce type d'action est *[factieux](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/factieux)*.

Comment: Merci, je ne connaissais pas cet adjectif ni ne l'avais jamais entendu. C'est pas que c'est rare que ça arrive, mais ça m'a supris. Mais duquel des pouvoirs légitimes s'agit-il par ailleurs, l'éxécutif, le législatif ou le judiciaire, et dans quelle proportion. Je conviens qu'il y a souvent une intégration de deux de ces pouvoirs selon le système politique observé.

Comment: Je comprends car *factieux* est assez passé de mode. De Gaulle l'avait un peu relancé au moment du putsch des généraux en Algérie. Le pouvoir légitime inclus l'exécutif et le législatif, celui qui est en place suivant la constitution en vigueur. Il est d'ailleurs peut-être arrivé lui aussi au pouvoir suite à un coup d'État antérieur, ce qui modère la notion de légitimité...